# Parsing cal output in POSIX compliant shell script by read command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, posix

I am trying to write a POSIX compliant script, which will print all months in specified year `$3`, that have day in `$1` (for example Mo, Tu,...) on a same date as `$2` (1,2,3,...).

Example:
Input: `./task1.sh Tu 5 2006`

Output:

```
September 2006
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
            1  2  3
4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30

December 2006
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
            1  2  3
4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

I have written this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
year=$3
dayInMonth=$2
dayInWeek=$1

index=1

while expr $index '!=' 13 >/dev/null; do
  cal -m $index $year| tail -n +2| while read Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su ; do
    eval theDay='$'$dayInWeek
    if [ "$theDay" = "$dayInMonth" ]; then
      cal -m $index $year;
    fi
  done
  index=$(expr $index + 1)
done
```

But there is a problem with reading of third line of cal output. In these lines numbers of days usually don't start at Mo place. How can I parse third line of cal output so the numbers in `$Mo`, `$Tu`, `$We`,... are always correct?

Comment: `cal -m` is not part of POSIX.

Comment: You can probably run the output of cal through sed, telling it to replace every sequence of three blanks with `0  ` (zero followed by two blanks).

Answer (score 2):

Update: You've added the requirement for a posix conform solution. `date -d` as used in my answer is not POSIX conform. I'll keep the answer for those who are using GNU/Linux.

Btw, the following command gives you posixly correct the day of week offset of Jan 5, 2006:

```
cal 01 2006 | awk -v d=5 'NR>2{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if($i==d){print i;exit}}}'
```

You need to tinker a little shell script around that.

---

I would use the `date` command, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dayofweek="${1}"
day="${2}"
year="${3}"

for m in {01..12} ; do
    date=$(LANG=C date -d "${year}-${m}-${day}" +'%a %B')
    read d m <<< "${date}"
    [ "${d}" = "${dayofweek}" ] && echo "${m}"
done
```

Results:

```
$ bash script.sh Thu 05 2006
January
October
```

Comment: I need posix standard friendly solution...But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to check dates with the command `date`.

```
for month in {1..12}; do 
  if [[ $(date -d $(printf "%s-%2.2d-%2.2d" "$year" "$month" "$day") "+%a") == "Tue" ]]; then 
    cal -m $month $year; 
  fi
done
```

The script loops over the 12 months and generate a date based on year and day. The `date` command outputs the day of the  in a 3 letters format with `+%a`.

If you want the day of week in number format, use `+%u` and `== 2` in the `if` statement.

Comment: There is hardly a single POSIX-compliant command in this answer.